# Joining a Legacy in Mage the Awakening

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

If I want to join a legacy in Mage, do I need to be a member of the parent path to do this? I can't find anywhere that says I do have to be, but I also can't see anywhere where it says you don't.

For example, would it be possible to have a [Transhuman Engineer](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Transhuman_Engineer) who is a Mastigos?

Comment: With a good story reason, I'd allow it. Having the Transhuman Engineers being a Free Council legacy and making it an Obrimos/Free Council legacy would be one route, as would finding that one Engineer willing to take on a Mastigos apprentice. But taking a Legacy out of canon path/order for reasons of stat line isn't a good enough reason.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the specific legacy descriptions have information on whether a given legacy is available for mages walking a different path than the legacy's parent. It *is* possible in some cases to do so:

> **Legacies are learned by way of a mage’s Path, although some orders can
>   teach certain Path Legacies to members not of that Path.**

– M:tAw p.344

For example, the "Subtle Ones" legacy is available for mages who are Obrimos *and/or* are members of the Guardians of the Veil, whereas "The Orphans of Proteus" are exclusively of the Thyrsus path (besides the specification of their "Parent Path", their "Organization" entry also points this out: "All Orphans are Thyrsus (...)".

**Edit:** As for your example, I think Transhuman Engineers *have* to be Obrimos, since that's what their Parent Path defines (unlike, for example, The Stone Scribes from the same book - Legacies: The Sublime -, who have a "Parent Path or Order" definition with "Moros *or* Mysterium" specified.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do. Either be on the same Path or be a part of the same Order. This is explicitly defined in the first mentions of Legacies in the gamebook and explained in detailed in the Legacies section.

On a sidenote, being a "transhumanist engineer" has nothing to do with being a part of a Legacy like being a chiropracter or sanitation worker would not affect the Order a Mage can join. Now, if you're asking if it would *fit* with a particular Legacy, then that's a different matter...

Comment: When you get a chance, could you add page number cites for "the first mentions of Legacies in the gamebook and explained in detailed in the Legacies section"?

Comment: The OP's referring to a particular legacy in that second paragraph; he's just misspelled it. I've added a link.